# CodeIgniter - single row query from second database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to get single row from another database than default (second database is connected in database.php and its working with another controller).

**My model:**

```
public function pobierz( $id_kontaktu )
{


    $osoby = $this->load->database('osoby', TRUE);
    return $osoby->where('id_osoby', $id_kontaktu)->row();


}
```

**My controller:**

```
public function kontakt()
{
    $data['kontakt_id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);   

    $kontakt = $this->Aktualizacja_m->pobierz( $data['kontakt_id'] );   
    echo $kontakt->email1;
}
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row() in
>   ... A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row()
>
> Filename: models/Aktualizacja_m.php
>
> Line Number: 21
>
> Backtrace:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting table name

```
public function pobierz( $id_kontaktu )
{
     $osoby = $this->load->database('osoby', TRUE);
     return $osoby->where('id_osoby', $id_kontaktu)->get('TABLE_NAME')->row_object();
}
```